# trying to skew 1 side of rectangle using gradient but getting jagged edges, can anyone suggest a fix?

Tags: css

I've created a rectangular button and want to skew one side, I'm trying to do this by using a gradient but the skewed edge is really jaggy. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to smooth this? I've tried adding `translate3d(0,0,0)` but with no success.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/7YmP4/

My **CSS**

```
div {

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

a {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display: block;
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(-72deg, transparent 75px, black 76px);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(-72deg, transparent 75px, black 76px);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(-72deg, transparent 75px, black 76px);
    background:linear-gradient(-72deg, transparent 75px, black 76px);
    margin:15px;
    position:relative;  
}
```

Comment: Well basically the problem is you're using the wrong tools. Seeing that you target recent browsers, have you thought of using SVG?

Comment: hey George, yeah SVG is a possibility. Just wanted to see if this could be achieved using just CSS but the jagged edges seem to be a problem

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not able to do nice soft edges, the only real way to do it using CSS would be to use a png background image with the cut edge and that will give you a nice smooth edge other than that you could look at using SVG.